Did Buddha ever taught about the Trisvabhava?
I am learning Mahayana. Today I came across a question on web “ Why Buddha taught Trisvabhava or three natures?”.
I was surprised because reality is empty of any essence but I found the word svabhava in Trisvabhavanirdesa which means three self becoming teachings.
I am aware of three lakhshana or three marks of existence.
Is there any sutta or sutra where Buddha mentions three svabhavas ?
